# How to animate UIView using constraint from bottom to top?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutanchor

I am creating UIView programmatically and after that i will animate that view from bottom to top using constraints. But animations doesnot show on this view object.

```
        overlay!.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        contentView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true

        let width: CGFloat = vc.view.frame.width - 40 - 16
        stringHeight = calculateEstimatedHeight(width: width, text: text) + 16
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stringHeight).isActive = true

        bottomConstraint = contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor, constant: stringHeight)
        bottomConstraint.isActive = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            self.showToastViewWithAnimation(viewController: vc)
        }


@objc func showToastViewWithAnimation(viewController: Any) {
        if let vc = viewController as? ViewController {

            vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
                self.bottomConstraint.constant = -20
                vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is messageLabel created in code? I'd  need the code for that, the stringHeight etc. etc. if not I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I think `vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()` is not needed it will update your layout automatically.

Comment: @CodeChanger layout will not be updated automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pointed out a few things via comments, read the comment and you will understand what is the issue in your code, check below code.

=> your code : `overlay!.addSubview(contentView)`

```
   @objc func showToastViewWithAnimation(viewController: Any) {
            if let vc = viewController as? ViewController {
                //vc.view.layoutIfNeeded() - this is not required before updating constraint value
                self.bottomConstraint.constant = -20 //update contstraint outside of the animation block
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {                
                    //vc.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
                    self.overlay?.layoutIfNeeded() //you needs to layout the overlay view, as your other toast views are added in overlay view and not in view of viewcontroller as per your code
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: send me your demo project at hirendra.developer@gmail.com and I will check that in details, will try to reply ASAP

Comment: @RahulChopra  check your inbox, I have fixed your code and replied in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Your Code:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and in Your ShowToastView function first find that which one is bottom constraint and then try to update it like this (Remember its a hint code you can update it according to your requirement):

```
@objc func showToastViewWithAnimation(viewController: Any) {
    if let vc = viewController as? ViewController {
        if let bottom = self.contentView.superview?.constraints.first(where: { (constraint) -> Bool in
        return constraint.firstAttribute == .bottom}){ 
// in this condition find your bottom constraint and update it, don't save your constraint in a variable.
           bottom.constant = -20 
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {               
             vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()
           }) { (complete) in

           }
        }
    }
}
```